# Inserting an image to a PDF form using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext

There are several articles related to this topic, but what I was able to do is inserting an image into a PDF file not a field inside a PDF form.

I am successfully able to insert text into a PDF form using iText Sharp,

The class is as the following:

```
public class ProcessForm__EmpApp_En
{
    public static void ProcessForm(SMDEntities _DB, WebApplicationFirstPhase EL)
    {
        string __EA_Form_Template = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/BaseFiles/OriginalFormTemplate.pdf");
        string newEAForm = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/CandidateForms/EA_" + EL.CandidateKey + ".pdf");

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(__EA_Form_Template);
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newEAForm, FileMode.Create));
        AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

        // set form pdfFormFields
        pdfFormFields.SetField("Txt_DC_01", EL.ApplicationDistributionCenter);
        pdfFormFields.SetField("Txt_Edu04_Start_Date", EL.Education4StartDate);
        pdfFormFields.SetField("Txt_Edu04_End_Date", EL.Education4EndDate);
        pdfFormFields.SetField("Txt_Edu04_Address", EL.Education4Address);

        //I have an Image field called "ImageLogo" and I don't know how to insert my logo in it?

    }
}
```

I searched a lot and I found some solution but they are not working. Probably they are outdated? For example, I found an article on Stackoverflow about similar issue and it look like the issue was solved. When I applied the same changes, I got an error.

The article link: [iTextSharp Fill Pdf Form Image Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44794670/itextsharp-fill-pdf-form-image-field)

My code (taken from the above article):

```
        string pdfTemplate = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/CandidateForms/OriginalFormTemplate.pdf");
        var newFile = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/CandidateForms/EA_" + EL.CandidateKey + ".pdf");
        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
        var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
        var pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

        string TestImage = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/CandidateImages/TestLogo.JPG");
        PushbuttonField ad = pdfFormFields.GetNewPushbuttonFromField("ImageLogo");
        ad.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY;
        ad.ProportionalIcon = true;
        ad.Image = Image.GetInstance(TestImage);
        pdfFormFields.ReplacePushbuttonField("ImageLogo", ad.Field);

        pdfStamper.Close();
```

Whenever I try to debug the code, I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: My guess is your test image has no form field `ImageLogo`. [You'll have to debug it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/). And [don't post images of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Comment: @DourHighArch your guess was right! You pointed me to the right direction and I thank you for that. Although I named the field "Image1", Adobe professional assigned a different name to it, now after correcting the field name it worked!